# USB Mouse not working 16.04.3 on x64 bit computer

Tags: 16.04, drivers, mouse, gui, gpu-driver

So whenever I switch between two windows, my mouse does the following:

1. Gets stuck in text cursor mode
2. Can no longer drag windows
3. Can no longer left click or right click

I will paypal someone $10 bucks if they can help fix this god awful problem. Also I cannot upgrade because I need to be on this specific release of ubuntu, well 16.04 in general. I have tried 16.04.4 as well and have had the same issue. I don't know what to do anymore.. Please help. The mouse I'm using is optical and does not have drivers, the mouse before that had drivers and had the same issues as well.

Comment: by two windows , do you mean two monitors or two different process/ application?

Comment: Two different processes/applications on the same monitor. One more thing I have noticed, this bug comes about after hovering over text in the terminal.

Comment: Does that happen with the PS2 Mouse as well? (If you can). Does that same thing happen in different USB Port as well?

Comment: USB ports made a difference. I hope I do not have this problem again.. I will try a PS2 mouse.  Thank you for your help.